# Any built-in Linux methods for AXI-burst type devices?

Tags: linux, arm, fpga, dma, amba

I need to communicate with an FPGA device based on an AXI-burst interface. What are the ways to access such a device through Linux without involving a DMA? Burst is an intrinsic property of the AXI standard, which should typically be triggered automatically when large amounts of data are being transferred. And the bigger problem is the FPGA is designed so as to respond only to burst-type requests over the AXI bus. So this causes serious issues on Linux when the application tries sequential copy. I have already tried `memcpy` and it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the other constraints on memory accesses ? Strongly ordered ? Device ?

Comment: Is this a Xilinx Zync or Altera SoC or something else?  Have you tried `mmap`ing the address region?  There's a good tutorial for Altera SoC [here](http://zhehaomao.com/blog/fpga/2013/12/27/sockit-3.html).  Also read through [these](http://blogs.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2013/05/29/) [blog](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/write-combining-is-not-your-friend/) [posts](http://blogs.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2013/05/30/) about write-combining MMIO access (for x68 rather than ARM but still good context).

Comment: The device is an ARM Cortex A9 based Zynq SoC.Ordering - not explicitly specified.

Comment: @Chiggs - I have tried mmap and memcpy. However it ends up triggering single read/write requests.

Comment: How many bytes is required by the hardware per burst? The largest transfer you will be able to do from the ARM CPU is from LDM/STM instructions. Anything larger will require DMA.

Comment: Here is a link to an [ldm/stm question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183405/how-to-prevent-ldm-stm-instructions-expansion-in-arm-compiler-5-armcc-inline-ass) where the OP is trying the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your “FPGA device” is a custom block, memory-mapped over AXI interface to Cortex-A9. I think there are 2 or 3 ways you could make this work.

1) Cacheable mapping. Cache hardware interface does burst-transfer of an entire cache line at a time. You would need to manually clean (after writes) and invalidate (before reads).

2) Non-cacheable mapping, and have an ARM assembly language routine handle the low-level transfer. I think the “Load and Store Multiple registers” instructions can provide what you are looking for.

I had a similar problem where an AXI peripheral (custom memory controller) needed to be accessed with 8-byte transfers from Cortex-A9 processor. The usual ARM instructions, of course, transfer 1, 2, or 4 bytes (byte, halfword, word). Those worked through cacheable mapping, but not through non-cacheable mapping. [LDM/STM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihcadda.html), 2 words at a time, worked with both mappings.

AHB/AXI transfer modes are implementation dependent, of course. Per your description, you need INCR or WRAP modes rather than SINGLE. But it should not have to be that way. That brings up the third way you could make this work:

3) Talk with your digital hardware designer, make him aware of the software impact of his implementation.

In my opinion, you shouldn’t have to do unusual / custom low-level MMU operations. Linux has high-level methods, you would put standard hooks in your device driver and/or board.c, the main option is whether to go uncached (i.e. COHERENT). Refer to [LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/?u=chp-15-sect-4).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the MMU to inform the hardware of the capabilities of your component.  You also need to ensure that the entire interconnect supports bursts and isn't doing any conversions (which can happen if there's any ambiguity about your component's capabilities when the interconnect is generated).

To set up the MMU you perform a call like this:

```
/* shareable device: S=b0 TEX=b000 AP=b11, C=b0, B=b1 = 0xC06*/
Xil_SetTlbAttributes(COMPONENT_BASE_ADDRESS, 0xC06);
```

attributes are defined as follows (from [Zynq Technical Reference Manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf)):

```
Encoding Bits   Cache Attribute
  C   B
  0   0         Non-cacheable
  0   1         Write-back, write-allocate
  1   0         Write-through, no write-allocate
  1   1         Write-back, no write-allocate
```

So the above line would set the region to write-back, write allocate, which *may* give you burst access on write.

See also [Xilinx AR#47406](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/47406.htm) and [this forum post](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Processor-System-Design/Zynq-AXI-Master-GP-burst-access/td-p/331021).

Comment: Thanks, I went through the links. But is this doable under Linux? I need this to work in a Linux driver wherein I won't be able to use Xil_SetTlbAttributes();

Comment: @AshishKulkarni can you not just include `xil_mmu.h` in Linux?  Otherwise you could look through the source code an work out how it's setting the MMU.

Comment: I will look through that. Also, I need more of a burst _read_ access rather than _write_.. Will this solution work for both?

Comment: @AshishKulkarni write-back usually means reads+writes are cached by the CPU (L1/L2) cache, writes may be done at any time and may be reordered;  The memory may be pre-fetched or read speculatively so reads mustn't have side effects. You need to look through the ARM manuals though as behaviour is architecture specific: [L2C-310 Cache controller](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0246h/index.html) and [MMU 500](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0517b/index.html)